# Optimizing sql query containing function in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check whether an IP exist in a database after it has been generated.My code works but it takes a whole 6 seconds to execute the following function `50,000` times. I am on PHP 7 (MySQL 5.7.11) but i will use `mariadb` in production.

How can i modify the sql to make it execute faster

```
function ip_exist ($db,$ipv6_address) {

    $db->query("SELECT ipv6 FROM tbl_ipv6 WHERE ipv6 = inet6_aton(:ip)  LIMIT 1");
    $db->bind(':ip', $ipv6_address);
    $db->single();
    if ($db->rowCount() > 0) {
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

SQL

```
    CREATE TABLE `tbl_ipv6` (
      `ipv6` varbinary(16) NOT NULL,
      `email_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `tbl_ipv6`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ipv6`);
```

No of rows in table : 4

**Update 2**
Query becomes the following (Thanks Bernd Buffen)

```
$db->query("SELECT ipv6 FROM tbl_ipv6 WHERE ipv6 = inet6_aton(:ip)");
```

Comment: Since you're just checking that an IP address exists you can also just do `SELECT 1 FROM ...` and check whether the result is true/false - this will have much less of an effect than adding the appropriate index though.

Answer (score 1):

Create a INDEX on this Column:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_ipv6
ADD KEY (ipv6);
```

now try again:

if the ips are unique you can set the key unique.

Comment: @user2650277 a primary key *is* an index - you don't need both

Comment: tell a bit more. Which engine you are using. how many records in the table, please post the output from SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_ipv6; and which Version you using

Comment: and please post also the output from : EXPLAIN SELECT ipv6 FROM tbl_ipv6 WHERE ipv6 = inet6_aton(:ip)  LIMIT 1. NOTE: if you have the Primary key on ipv6 or a unique key you dont use LIMIT 1. there is only one record

Comment: @BerndBuffen i added your changes but improvement isn't significant...check post for updates